# Intent to use my app to select a ringtone

Tags: android, android-intent, ringtone

I want my app to be among the options when a user wants to select a ringtone in their settings.

I can't find info on that. I was thinking I could put an intent filter in the manifest but can't find good documentation on that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code  -

```
Uri alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
mp= MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), alert);
mp.setVolume(100, 100);
mp.start();
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener(){
@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp){
mp.release();
}
});

vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService (VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
vibrator.vibrate(400);
```

Comment: How does this do what the OP wants?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.RINGTONE_PICKER"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Some HTC devices also require `HTC_RINGTONE_PICKER` in addition to the above.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for collect the available tone from your device

```
private String[] getMusic() {
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                final Cursor mCursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                                new String[] { MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME }, null,
                                null, "LOWER(" + MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + ") ASC");

                int count = mCursor.getCount();

                String[] songs = new String[count];
                int i = 0;
                if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        do {
                                songs[i] = mCursor.getString(0);
                                i++;
                        } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
                }

                mCursor.close();

                return songs;
        }
```

Display in the **list view** and set using below comment

```
ContentValues content = new ContentValues(); 
                                               content.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,ringtoneFile.getAbsolutePath());
content.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "ownringtone");
content.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/*");
content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "name");
content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);
// Insert it into the database
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(ringtoneFile.getAbsolutePath());
pathString= ringtoneFile.getAbsolutePath();
Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, content);
RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getBaseContext(), RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,newUri);
```

this help full to you